# Using SSIS :What is better between using REST API or querying a database directly?

Tags: sql-server, rest, t-sql, ssis, data-warehouse

I am working on creating a data warehouse for a client. To extract data, I can use :

- Direct T-SQL queries to the production database
- API/JSON

I want to know what is better concerning the **data quality** and **performance** between these two alternatives ?

Comment: From what i understood, you are creating a SQL Server DWH database. But, to answer your question, i think it's important to know where data come from. If you're extracting data from a SQL source, use T-SQL. Specially if data comes from another SQL Server instance. Are you using SSIS?

Comment: Yes I am using SSIS.

Comment: And what is the data source?

Comment: I can use tables from SQL server or an API.

Comment: Use SQL tables, transport should be over TCP and performance are at the best (if you use bulk operations)

Comment: Data quality, i would say it depends over lots of conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are importing data from a SQL Server instance to another SQL Server instance (DWH) and you have the possibility to use SSIS, go with T-SQL or direct bulk operations you can find as components in the VS toolbox. SQL Server Source and SQL Server Destination should meet your requirements.

Comment: This is a very incomplete answer. Performance considerations extend beyond an efficient data transfer to the warehouse. If your ETL tasks are putting undue strain on the source system, nobody's going to be talking about how "efficient" the ETL process is, they're going to be telling you to shut it down. And then they'll be asking why you didn't use the available API. The question is too broad, and the answer is too narrow.